# Rails: delete on scoped association behaves differently than just delete from the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations

I have a project based on Rails 4.2.

I have defined two models like this:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_options
    has_many :items, through: :item_options, source: :item 

    scope :materials, -> { where(category: 'material') }
    scope :types, -> { where(category: 'type') }

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_options
    has_many :options, through: :item_options
```

I'm not able to delete association's join records through the scopes of the Option model.

If I do:

```
Item.first.options.materials.delete_all
```

the executed query is:

```
DELETE FROM "options" WHERE "options"."id" IN (SELECT "options"."id" FROM "options" INNER JOIN "item_options" ON "options"."id" = "item_options"."option_id" WHERE "item_options"."item_id" = $1 AND "options"."category" = $2)
```

That removes records from the Option model and it's not what I was expecting.

If I try to delete association records without using a scope, like this:

```
Item.first.options.delete_all
```

that correctly executes the query:

```
DELETE FROM "item_options" WHERE "item_options"."item_id" = $1
```

Effectively removing only the join records.

Why does delete behave differently if called through a scope?

(edited, contained a pasting error with old name LabelItem for one of the models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the method `materials` in the `options` relation it returns an `Option` relation instance. That's why it won't work.

It might work:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_options
    has_many :options, through: :item_options
    has_many :material_options, -> { materials }, through: :item_options, source: :option
```

Then:

`Item.first.material_options.delete_all`

Comment: OP's `Item.first.options.materials` and `Item.first.options` actually both return `Option` records (or "relation instance", in your terms, as far as I understood your statement). They however are different instance types: `Item.first.options.materials` returns a type of `Option::ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` while `Item.first.options` returns  a type of `Option::ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`. My gut feeling is that this difference somewhere leads to an explanation on the OP's question. But I cannot verify, at the moment.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario you are correct about the different return types. Nevertheless I expected the delete method to work in both scenarios. I wanted to define scopes on Option model because I can reuse them for other cases.

Comment: Correct, both return options. The key part here the type of the relation, they behave differently

Comment: Ok @sickrandir, edited the answer. Now reusing the `materials` scope, which is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe explain or point me to some docs to understand why scope returns a Relation and not a CollectionProxy?